# Setting node label's size and color in TiKZ?

Tags: labels, tikz-styles

I'm drawing AVL trees using the first answer given at [AVL Trees in TikZ: draw outside of node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54559/avl-trees-in-tikz-draw-outside-of-node) as an example.

All I want to do is add a style definition which will draw the labels in a small font and in blue.  I can of course do that individually for each label, but it would be more elegant to set it as a style.  The style I have so far is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1},
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  label distance=-1mm]
```

which works fine - but how do I add blue text and small font size to those labels?

Note that I create each label by its angle and text:

```
node [label=30:\small $1$] {6}
```

or for a color

```
node [label={[blue]30:\small $1$}] {6}
```

Anyway, I'd like to format the labels as part of the style.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE! You have enough experience on this site to do that. BTW, `node[label={[font=\small,text=blue]30:$-1$}] {10}` should work.

Answer (score 7):

There is no problem whatsoever to make the label font blue and small in the answer you are referring to.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1},
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  label distance=-1mm,
   edge from parent path=
    {(\tikzparentnode.south) .. controls +(0,-.5) and +(0,.5)
                             .. (\tikzchildnode.north)},
   every node/.style={draw,circle},
   label distance=-1mm]
\node [label={[font=\small,text=blue]30:$-1$}]{50}
  child {node[label={[font=\small,text=blue]30:$-1$}] {10}}
  child {node[label={[font=\small,text=blue]30:$0$}] {20}
  child {node[label={[font=\small,text=blue]30:$-1$}] {10}}
  child {node[label={[font=\small,text=blue]30:$-1$}] {20}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is easy enough to turn this into a style.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1},
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  label distance=-1mm,
   edge from parent path=
    {(\tikzparentnode.south) .. controls +(0,-.5) and +(0,.5)
                             .. (\tikzchildnode.north)},
   every node/.style={draw,circle},
   label distance=-1mm,
   my label/.style n args={2}{label={[font=\small,text=blue]#1:#2}}]
\node [my label={30}{$-1$}]{50}
  child {node[my label={30}{$-1$}] {10}}
  child {node[my label={30}{$0$}] {20}
  child {node[my label={-30}{$-1$}] {10}}
  child {node[my label={-60}{$-1$}] {20}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I was trying to avoid writing the size and colour in every label, but instead include it as part of the style definition.

Comment: Oh now that's fine - thank you!  Can you also include the degree as a parameter to "my label"? - sometimes a label at 30 degrees (in my tree which has straight edges) will be written over an edge.

Comment: @Alasdair Done.

Comment: Perfect! The "n args" is new to me. Thank you very much indeed!